# Boolean expression A׳B׳C+A׳BC׳+AB׳C׳+ABC'

Tags: boolean-algebra

How do i simplify this boolean expression with steps? I am so lost for some reason. I entered it into my logic converter on multisim and did recieve the simplified version.

A׳B׳C+A׳BC׳+AB׳C׳+ABC'

Comment: Try kmap?.......

Comment: We havent learned them yet. I was put in this class because I scored high so I'm a bit behind in what they know va me and just looking for help.

Comment: Ohk kmap is not necessary... Iet me grab a paper.:)

Comment: Okay thank you. I will try... I appreciate you:)

Answer (score 0):

$$A'B'C+A'BC'+AB'C'+ABC'$$

With out kmap, you just have to eyeball:
1) Last two terms have $AC'$ as common
2) $2$nd and last terms have $BC'$ as common
So group them like this:
 $$A'B'C+(A'BC'+ABC')+(AB'C'+ABC')$$

Factor out the common and see if you can take it from there.